# AWS EC2 Dedicated host resources sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm in the process of designing a DC migration to AWS.

For compliance requirements client needs to run some servers in side a dedicated host.

If I choose c5 as the host model and `4xlarge` as instance type, I'm allowed to create maximum 4 `c5.4xlarge` instances inside 1 host.

At a time if I run only two `c5.4xlarge` instances inside the host and during instances peak times will the host share rest of the hardware resources from its maximum allowed capacity, with two running instances?

[image: Please see the attachment]

Comment: What are your customer requirements for needing a Dedicated Host? Have they considered using a Dedicated Instance instead? In general, a Dedicated Host is only required if you need to meet strict licensing requirements, like Oracle licenses that are based per-processor.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd like to remind you that you're already paying for the whole dedicated host, independent of the size or count of the boxes running on it. So you can use to the host to its max limits, from a cost/performance point of view.

Autoscaling and placement groups are not allowed on dedicated hosts, as mentioned in the aws documentation.